# WIFI dropping in Lenovo Thinkpad T410

Tags: wireless, 14.04, lenovo

My wifi is constant dropping and i am not able to get a consistent connection , not even for a minute. My laptop is a Lenovo Thinkpad T410 and the Ubuntu 14.04 is a fresh install. So is this a kernel problem or my laptop wifi card problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu is more than likely not the issue.  I have a Lenovo G580 running 14.04 and had the same issue.  I solved it by adding a Netgear usb wifi adapter.  Problem solved for my Lenovo.  The dropped connections occurred on both Windows and Ubuntu, before I added the Netgear adapter.

ADDITIONAL INFO

To check your reception quality you can create a script file running in a continuous loop.
The following script will yield, "Link quality" and "Signal level".  The signal level reads in a negative number mine shows "-36" on the lowest to "-50" highest.  Lowest number is best.  If you are reading -85 to -100 or more, this may be the source of your dropped connection.

You can run this test for yourself with the following script.

Open a terminal window Ctrl-alt-t.

```
touch  wlan0tst.sh
chmod ugo+x
gedit wlan0tst.sh
```

Enter the following lines in the gedit window.

```
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
    /sbin/iwconfig wlan0 | grep Link | tr '\n' '\r'
done
```

Save the file.  From the terminal.

```
./wlan0tst.sh
```

To terminate the loop "ctrl-c" or just close the Terminal window.

Comment: Correct. I am going to have to check my wifi adapter card. Is there any way i can do that exercise ?

Comment: The information for monitoring you signal strength received was too long for a comment.  See edited answer under ADDITIONAL INFO.  Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer !! will try the script and let u no the results !

Comment: I am getting around "-66". So this means that there is a problem with my wifi adapter or my source ?

Comment: It could be either one, but this sounds like a harware problem not an Ubuntu problem.  Try moving closer to the router and check the signal. Also, you can install "wavemon" from software center, gives a graphic display of results, with color bars. Runs from Terminal with "wavemon".